# Ajax Zip file download - WordPress Guru

Tags: php, wordpress

Here, I am not able to download any Zip file. This code is creating the Zip, also, but I can't download it. Please, anyone who knows of WordPress/PHP Guru, help me.

This custom JS is passed the data to `img_zip` and the `img_zip()` function can call the `zipDownload` function with images and its resort name. The `zipDownload()` also got an images array and resort name, but I think the Zip is also created too. At the response time, I am not able to download the Zip file. Please guide me.

**.php**

```
<button type="button" class="cart-detail select-and-download" data-resortname ="<?php echo $resort_title ?>" data-type="<?php echo $resort_type ?>" data-postid="<?php echo get_the_ID() ?>" data-keyword="<?php echo $resort_data[$keyword_field] ?>"  data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample" >
     Download
</button>
```

**custom.js**

```
$('.select-and-download').click(function () {

  params = [];
  postid = $(this).data('postid');
  keyword  = $(this).data('keyword');
  type = $(this).data('type');
  resort = $(this).data('resort');
  resort_name = $(this).data('resortname');


  let selectedValues = getValueUsingClass();

  data = {
    action: 'img_zip',
    resort_name : resort_name,
    postid: postid,
    selectedValues: selectedValues,
    keyword: keyword,
    type: type,
  };
  $.ajax({
    url: ajaxurl,
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    success: function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    },
  });
});

});
```

**Function.php**

```
function img_zip() {
  $resort_name = $_REQUEST['resort_name']; 
  $images = $_POST['selectedValues']; 

  zipDownload($images,$resort_name); 
}

function zipDownload($files, $resort_name)

    {
// var_dump($files);      // all images in array
// var_dump($resort_name); // resort name

    ini_set('memory_limit','20048M');
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $zipName = $resort_name.'_'.date("d_m_Y").'_'.get_current_user_id().'.zip';
    $filename = get_template_directory().'/downloads/'.$zipName;
    // die($filename);
    if ($zip->open($filename, ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE)
    {
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            // echo $file; //here i am get image url

            $zip->addFromString(basename($file),file_get_contents($file, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH));
        }
        $zip->close();
    }
    header("Content-type: application/zip");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $zipName);
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
    readfile($filename);
    unlink($filename);
    echo $filename;

}
```

Comment: You need to clarify a few things I think - Is the ZIP folder ever being created? If so, can you confirm this on the server? Have you checked into any error logs to see if there is something failing? What does the PHP script look like?

Comment: please dont post code in the comments section.. edit your question with a formatted block

Comment: You should probably check if the file was created or not before trying to read and output it to the browser. Never just assume...

Comment: Are you trying to download the zip through Ajax? That won't work. You should create the zip, return the url to the file and then redirect the user to that URL. Btw, how is the function `zipDownload()` called?

Comment: As @Ice76 already pointed out: *Don't post code in the comment section*. It unreadable. Edit your question to include _all_ relevant code and info.

Comment: I have updated .php code and zipDownload() function call code. It is not possible to download zip in this way ? 
I think it is may be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't trigger a download using ajax but you can archieve what you are looking for, replace your .$ajax call with this:

```
var downloadForm = $('<form method="post" action="' + ajaxurl + '">');
downloadForm.append('<input type="hidden" name="action" value="img_zip" />');
downloadForm.append('<input type="hidden" name="resort_name" value="' + resort_name + '" />');
downloadForm.append('<input type="hidden" name="postid" value="' + postid + '" />');
downloadForm.append('<input type="hidden" name="keyword" value="' + keyword + '" />');
downloadForm.append('<input type="hidden" name="type" value="' + type + '" />');
downloadForm.appendTo('body');
downloadForm.submit();
downloadForm.remove();
```